# Can't activate 'remember' in org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I can't get 'remember' to work in org-mode of emacs.

I'm on snow leopard.

I added

(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") 'org-remember)
to my .emacs file but when I try to use that shortcut it says:
Wrong type argument: commandp, remember

So I added 
(org-remember-insinuate)

and when I start emacs it says:
symbol's function definition is void org-remember-insinuate

Ideas?

GNU Emacs 22.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the obvious stuff...

Have you ensured that `org-remember` was loaded?  i.e. by adding this to your .emacs:

```
(require 'org-remember)
```

And, while you're at it, have you ensured that `remember` can load properly also?

```
(require 'remember)
```

`remember` is a separate package from `org`, which you'll have to download.  Check out the [wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RememberMode).

You'll want to ensure that the `org` and `remember` packages are in your load path **before** you require the libraries, with something like:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/orgdir/lisp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/remember")
(require 'remember)
(require 'org-remember)
```

Note: Emacs 22 comes with `org-mode`, but not a recent version.  You need the more recent version in order to get the `org-remember` package.

Comment: I tried that and got "cannot open load file", "org-remember"

but then I explicit added the path to the libraries and it worked! (add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp/org-mode/lisp/")

I thought they were found automatically. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon. That makes remember work, but now other stuff is broken such as C-c C-a to unfold all levels in file

Comment: @99miles, need more information.  Without loading remember/org-remember, what was `C-c C-a` bound to, and afterwords, what is it bound to?   `C-h k C-c C-a` will tell you what it's bound to.

Comment: It's not loading remember that breaks it, it's the load-path line:
C-c C-a runs the command show-all
  which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `outline.el'.
It is bound to C-c C-a, <menu-bar> <Org> <Show/Hide> <Show All>.
(show-all)

Comment: @99miles Does `M-x show-all` still work?  I don't see any real connection between changing the `load-path` variable to enable the loading of the packages changing how `show-all` functions.  Loading the packages might have some effect...

Comment: yes, that still works. add-to-list shouldn't be overwriting any existing paths that are being loaded, right? weird

Comment: when i include the load-path line, and do C-c C-a it get: Symbol's function definition is void: org-attach

Comment: @99miles The fact that after you've done the load-path line `C-c C-a` is bound to something *different* is important (your earlier comment said it wasn't rebound).  I updated my answer to emphasize the fact that the changes to `load-path` should be *before* the `require` statements.  Are you doing that?  If not, then you might be mixing files from the org-mode distributed with Emacs, and your newer copy.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that it no longer worked like it used to. Yes, I have the load-path before the require. I'll look into the possibility of mixing files. thanks

Comment: i pulled all the files from org-mode/lisp/, then re-added one by one the files it complained about when i started emacs (just 2 files), and now everything seems ok so far. thanks!